# RADIUS authentication requests not relayed to RADIUS server

Tags: cisco, switch, radius, freeradius, eap

I am trying to set up a RADIUS server for 802.1x NAC over a Cisco IE 3000 Network Switch, using freeRadius to implement it.

I know the switch knows where the RADIUS server is because I set up the switch to authenticate the enable and login passwords to be authenticated through the server. However, when I plug in a supplicant in on one of the supplicant-designated switches, it sends a `EAPOL Start` request to `Nearest`, according to Wireshark. The switch does not see the attempts to send this request.

What configuration option, on either the supplicant end or the switch end, do I need to change in order for the request for authentication to be sent from the supplicant to the RADIUS server?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to define radius servers and 802.1x related interface parameters. Make sure that you configured AAA lists for 802.1x

```
aaa authentication dot1x default group <your radius group for dot1x name>
aaa authorization network default group <your radius group for dot1x name>
aaa accounting dot1x default start-stop group <your radius group for dot1x name>
```